Understanding why a derivative in a nonabelian gauge theory jumps over a field in Peskin and Schroeder, eq. (16.32)
I'm learning about ghosts in gauge theories in chapter 16 of Peskin and Schroeder. I'm pretty good with everything going on in chapter 16.2, except for eq. (16.32) and the discussion below.
Eq. (16.32) is given by $$\mathcal{L}_\text{ghost} = \overline{c}^a (- \partial^2 \delta^{ac} - g \partial^\mu f^{abc} A^b_\mu)c^c.\tag{16.32}$$ According to the discussion below, the derivative in the second term only hits the ghost field $c$ and $\textbf{not}$ the gauge field, even though notation seemingly implies that it does. Why is this the case?
EDIT: The exact sentence that confuses me is this

In the interaction term of (16.32), the derivative
stands to the left of the gauge field; this implies that this derivative is evaluated with the momentum coming out of the vertex along the ghost line.


I don't have the book so I'm not sure if this is right, but is it possible that the sentence means that you could think of $\bar{c}$ as the outgoing line from the vertex, and after integration by parts the derivative acts on $\bar{c}$, meaning the momentum from that line is relevant? (Or if you don't use integration by parts, conservation of momentum would mean that momentum was the sum of the other two)

@Andrew I see what you're saying. I would assume the derivative is acting on both $A_\mu$ and $c$ just by looking at the Lagrangian. But then an integration by parts makes this a derivative on $\overline{c}$ with an extra minus sign. However the quote says explicitly the ghost line and not the anti-ghost...

But maybe a ghost coming out is equivalent to an antighost coming in? I don't know, I would have to remind myself how it works, just wondering out loud if that might be what they meant.

@Andrew I think you are right. I've never really considered it, but this must be true for all QFTs right? That we can essentially move the derivative around in the Lagrangian by integration by parts to get something nicer?

Sometimes boundary terms do matter. But since they don't in the scenario you are asking about, then yes you have freedom in where you put the derivative and sometimes that can simplify a calculation.
